# How do I choose between Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

Their public interfaces appear similar.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) states that the SemaphoreSlim is a lightweight alternative and doesn't use Windows Kernel semaphores.  [This resource](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore) states that the SemaphoreSlim is much faster.  In what situations does the SemaphoreSlim make more sense over the Semaphore and vice versa?

Comment: Semaphore always passes the job to the OS.  That makes it relatively expensive if the semaphore is not strongly contested, the kernel call easily costs 400 nanoseconds.  The slim favor first tries to do it cheaply with a shared variable, only calls into the OS when that did not work.  You always like cheap, except in the corner case where the semaphore needs to be shared by multiple processes.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

One difference is that `SemaphoreSlim` does not permit named semaphores, which can be system-wide. This would mean that a SemaphoreSlim could not be used for cross-process synchronization.

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a.aspx) also indicates that SemSlim should be used when "wait times are expected to be very short". That would usually dovetail nicely with the idea that the slim version is more lightweight for most of the trade offs.

Comment: I wish MS had written something about what happens when wait times are not "very short".

Comment: ... or what "very short" means

Comment: +1 for the two comments above. can anyone shed any light on "very short"?

Comment: Depending on the system, 1 microsecond for Semaphore and 1/4 microsecond for SemaphoreSlim to do a WaitOne or Release ["C# 5.0 in a Nutshell" pg. 890] 

So maybe that's what they mean by very short wait times?

Comment: @dhsto Interesting info, and glad you included a reference.

Comment: @dhsto Good reference! But I'm guessing the linked article means "when wait times to access the shared resource are very short" - i.e. the resource will not remain in exclusive use for long periods of time - rather than meaning the wait times for the semaphore code itself? The semaphore code will always be executing regardless of how long the resource is kept locked.

Comment: @culix Looking at the source for Semaphore versus SemaphoreSlim I suspect the main reason that SemaphoreSlim should only be used for "very short" waits is because it uses a spin wait. This is more responsive, but eats up a lot of CPU and would be wasteful for longer wait periods where instantaneous responses are less important. Semaphore blocks the thread instead.

Comment: @r2_118 I believe a spin wait is used for `Wait` but not for `WaitAsync`. I wonder if the "very short" advice just means that something more durable/disk-backed should be used if it's going to need to wait for minutes or hours. I would think a lightweight object that supports asynchronous waiting would be very well suited to "sorta long" (a few seconds) wait times, which makes the advice a little confusing. In short, I concur with the others that they should explain it better. :)

Comment: FWIW I also wonder about the spinning, in the source the WaitAsync seems to add some the wait request to a linked list and Release seems to then check that list to signal the awaiting tasks.

Answer (score 41):

SemaphoreSlim is based on SpinWait and Monitor, so the thread that waits to acquire the lock is burning CPU cycles for some time in hope to acquire the lock prior to yielding to another thread. If that does not happen, then the threads lets the systems to switch context and tries again (by burning some CPU cycles) once the OS schedules that thread again. With long waits this pattern can burn through a substantial amount of CPU cycles. So the best case scenario for such implementation is when most of the time there is no wait time and you can almost instantly acquire the lock.

Semaphore relies on the implementation in OS kernel, so every time when you acquire the lock, you spend quite a lot of CPU cycles, but after that the thread simply sleeps for as long as necessary to get the lock.

Answer (score 22):

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a.aspx) describes the difference.

In one sentence:

- The SemaphoreSlim class represents a lightweight, fast semaphore that can be used for waiting within a single process when wait times are expected to be very short.

Comment: To add to this, use SemaphoreSlim in all cases where your application is the only process on your computer that is going to need to access that Semaphore.

Comment: @Salgat Why would you do that? As outlined in other answers, `SemaphoreSlim` is implemented using SpinWait, so if you wait on it a lot, you will waste a lot of CPU time. Which is not even a good idea if your process is the only process on the computer.

Comment: From the MSDN documentation, "The SemaphoreSlim class is the recommended semaphore for synchronization within a single app.". Except for special cases, you should default to using SemaphoreSlim if only one process is using that semaphore. Special exceptions generally exist for any concurrent data type, which goes without saying.

Answer (score 14):

Regarding "short times" controversy:

At least [SemaphoreSlim MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) states that

> The SemaphoreSlim class is the recommended semaphore for synchronization within a single app.

in Remarks section. Same section also tells the main difference between Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim:

> The SemaphoreSlim is a lightweight alternative to the Semaphore class that doesn't use Windows kernel semaphores. Unlike the Semaphore class, the SemaphoreSlim class doesn’t support named system semaphores. You can use it as a local semaphore only.

Comment: More details: `[SemaphoreSlim and other locks] use busy spinning for brief periods before they put the thread into a true Wait state. When wait times are expected to be very short, spinning is far less computationally expensive than waiting, which involves an expensive kernel transition`: https://dotnet.github.io/docs/essentials/collections/thread-safe-collections.html

Answer (score -3):

I looked at the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/threading/semaphore.cs,9329ec73e0564070) and this is what I came up with:

1. Both Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim use WaitHandle which internally uses Win32 native handle. Which is why you need to Dispose() both. So the notion that Slim is lightweight is suspect.
2. SemaphoreSlim uses SpinWait internally while Semaphore does not. That tells me that in cases where the wait is expected to be long, Semaphore should do better at least in the sense that it will not choke out your CPU.

Comment: SemaphoreSlim isn't derived from WaitHandle. Actually it was created with a single goal - to eliminate deriving from WaitHandle, which is kernel space primitive, in tasks where you need to synchronize operations inside only one process.

Comment: @IgorVSavchenko SemaphoreSlim isn't derived from WaitHandle, but it does hold a WaitHandle. See what it does inside Dispose - it disposes a member that is derived from WaitHandle.