# Semaphore lock resulting in a deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

```
public class SampleData
{
 private static readonly Semaphore pool = new Semaphore(0,1);

 public string Data => getFromFile();

 private static string getFromFile()
 {
   pool.WaitOne();
   var data = 
   File.ReadAllText("somefilepath");
    pool.Release();
    return data;
  }
}
```

In program.cs

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
   tasks.Add(Task.Run<string>(()=> 
    new SampleData().Data));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

When I run this, it never completes the tasks. Can any one tell me what's the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920216/semaphore-blocks-though-it-isnt-full

Answer (score 0):

If getFromFile() throw an exception, semaphore will never be released and Task.WaitAll will wait forever, you need to move pool.Release() to finally section. That might be the reason for indefinite waiting.

```
private static string getFromFile()
 {
   pool.WaitOne();
   try {
     var data = File.ReadAllText("somefilepath");
     return data;
   }
   finally {
     pool.Release();
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

You should consider using `SemaphoreSlim` if this is not *cross process*.

**Secondly**

In regards to your initialization of `Semaphore(0,1)`. If `initialCount` is less than `maximumCount`, the effect is the same as if the current thread had called `WaitOne` (`maximumCount` minus `initialCount`) times.

That's to say, when you call `pool.WaitOne();` in your current configuration, you are going to block until someone calls release (*straight off the bat*).

E.g.:

```
private static readonly Semaphore pool = new Semaphore(0,1);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   pool.WaitOne();
   Console.WriteLine("This will never get executed");
}
```

It's likely you want:

```
Semaphore(1,1)
// or
SemaphoreSlim(1,1)
```

**Lastly**

You must always wrap these *synchronization primitives* in a `try finally`, or you ***will*** eventually deadlock if an *exception* gets thrown before `Release`.

`SemaphoreSlim`

```
await pool.WaitAsync();
try
{
   // do something
}
finally
{
   pool.Release();
}
```

Or if you really need to use a `Semaphore`

```
pool.WaitOne();
try
{

  // do something
}
finally
{
   pool.Release();
}
```